# How to map a model to a database view using Datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

This sounds very simple however I cant seem to find a answer, how do you map a view to a model in datamapper? If I remove the ID field which my view doesnt have, datamapper complains, if I leave it there then everytime I execute a select it says my column id doesnt exist, because it's a view not a table.

Answer (score 0):

DataMapper 1.x does not have native support for views. It expects models to have at least one property that acts as the primary key.

This primary key will normally be used for specifying updates and lazy attribute loads.

When your view does have a column with unique values just specify `:key => true` in the property options that belong to this column.

No need to specify a property with the name `:id`.

When you do not have a column with unique value, use a compound primary key (CPK). A set of columns that form a unique combination of values:

```
class ModelFromView
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :key_like_property_a, String, :key => true
  property :key_like_property_b, Integer, :key => true
  property :other_property, Integer 
  ...
end
```